# TypeError: editMedicine is not a function - REACT

Tags: reactjs

Not sure where I am going wrong here. editMedicine should be a function but it is not. When I click the edit medicine button, I get an error onSubmit. I know in other areas of my code I had some misspellings and capitalization issues, I am hoping this is the case here . I have been looking at this for so long that I cant quite spot whats going on.

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState.js";
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";
 
const Editmedicine = (route) => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const { medicines, editMedicine } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const [selectedUser, setSeletedUser] = useState({
        id: null,
        name: "",
        directions: "",
    });
    const currentUserId = route.match.params.id;

    useEffect(() => {
        const medicineId = currentUserId;
        const selectedUser = medicines.find(
        (med) => med.id === parseInt(medicineId)
        );
        setSeletedUser(selectedUser);
    }, []);

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        editMedicine(selectedUser);
        history.push("/");
    };

    const handleOnChange = (userKey, value) =>
        setSeletedUser({ ...selectedUser, [userKey]: value });

    if (!selectedUser || !selectedUser.id) {
        return <div>sdf</div>;
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
        <div id="editContainer">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="w-full mb-5">
                <label
                htmlFor="name"
                >
                Name of medicine
                </label>
                <input
                    value={selectedUser.name}
                    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange("name", e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter name"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="w-full  mb-5">
                <label
                htmlFor="directions"
                >
                Directions
                </label>
                <input
                    value={selectedUser.directions}
                    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange("directions", e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter directions"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                <button id="editMedicine">
                Edit medicine
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="text-center mt-4 text-gray-500">
                <Link to="/">Cancel</Link>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Editmedicine;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

// here is the globalState file

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import AppReducer from "./AppReducer"; 

//start by setting the initial state
const initialState = {
    medicines: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Daily Multivitamin",
        directions: "Take once a day with 2 glasses of water"
        
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Herbal capsule",
        directions: "Take once a day with food"
        
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Tincture",
        directions: "1 drop a day, 3x a day."
        
    }
    ]
};

  //create context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);
  //provider component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    function removeMedicine(id) {
        dispatch({
            type: "REMOVE_MEDICINE",
            payload: id
        });
    }
    //this might have to be ADD_MEDICINE or S instead
    function addMedicine(medicines) {
        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_MEDICINE",
            payload: medicines
        });
    }

    function editMedicine(medicines) {
        dispatch({
            type: "EDIT_MEDICINE",
            payload: medicines
        });
    }
    return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
            value={{
            medicines: state.medicines,
            removeMedicine,
            addMedicine,
            editMedicine
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: Add the GlobalContext code as well to verify correct usage.